# SQL query - Find daily Min, Max and times when the Min and Max values occurred

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which looks like this one:

```
_Datetime           | Value
2015-05-01 06:00:00 | 12.3
2015-05-01 06:20:00 | 12.5
2015-05-01 06:40:00 | 12.3
2015-05-01 07:00:00 | 13.5
2015-05-01 07:20:00 | 14.5
2015-05-01 07:40:00 | 14.3
2015-05-01 08:00:00 | 18.2
2015-05-01 08:20:00 | 15.0
2015-05-01 08:40:00 | 15.0

2015-05-02 06:00:00 | 19.2
2015-05-02 06:20:00 | 7.3
2015-05-02 06:40:00 | 11.4
2015-05-02 07:00:00 | 9.5
2015-05-02 07:20:00 | 7.6
2015-05-02 07:40:00 | 6.6
2015-05-02 08:00:00 | 10.4
2015-05-02 08:20:00 | 19.3
2015-05-02 08:40:00 | 15.4

2015-05-03 06:00:00 | 8.7
2015-05-03 06:20:00 | 8.6
2015-05-03 06:40:00 | 8.6
2015-05-03 07:00:00 | 21.5
2015-05-03 07:20:00 | 12.4
2015-05-03 07:40:00 | 7.3
2015-05-03 08:00:00 | 10.8
2015-05-03 08:20:00 | 12.5
2015-05-03 08:40:00 | 10.6
```

I would like to:

-select min, max and avg for each day

-select time for which the min and max occurred (I want to select only one row - first that occurred)

```
_Date      | _Min  |  _MinTime  |  _Max  |  _MaxTime  |  Avg    |
2015-05-01 | 12.3  |  06:00:00  |  18.2  |  08:00:00  |  14.18  |
2015-05-02 |  6.6  |  07:40:00  |  19.3  |  08:20:00  |  11.86  |
2015-05-03 |  7.3  |  07:40:00  |  21.5  |  07:00:00  |  11.22  |
```

I can easily get the min, max and avg but I got stuck with the time.

Comment: Which database are you using? Mysql or sqlserver?

Comment: Please show the query that you have so far.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: look into the group by and having clauses of sql,  then come back with your best attempt at the sql and post it.

Comment: I am kind a new with SQL so the way I did it is probably not the best way. I created 3 views: first is getting the Min, Max and Avg and groups them by day, month and year. The second gets time of min value for each day and the third gets time of max value for each day. The problem I have now is that if there is more than one min or max value in the table for one day my view lists all of them. I would also like to have everything in one view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - should return only one set of values per day.  (Edited - added average, rounded it as suggested in comments).

```
; with cte as (
select *
    , cast (_datetime as date) as [DateFormat]
    , cast (_datetime as time) as [TimeFormat]
    , row_number() over (partition by cast (_datetime as date) order by Value, _datetime) RNmin
    , row_number() over (partition by cast (_datetime as date) order by Value desc, _datetime) RNmax
    , Avg(value) over (partition by cast (_datetime as date)) as AvgVal
from MyTable
)
select a.DateFormat, a.value as MinValue, a.TimeFormat as MinTime
     , b.value as MaxValue, b.TimeFormat as MaxTime
     , cast(a.AvgVal as decimal(5,2)) as AverageValue
from Cte a
join cte b
on a.DateFormat = B.Dateformat and a.RNmin = 1 and b.RNmax = 1
```

Comment: This returns same _MinTime and _MaxTime for all dates. Looking at the output above, that is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Yeah - that was an error when I originally posted.  It should be working now, @nepalirookie.  I was ordering by the wrong column; sorry about that.

Comment: This should be working now. Just a suggestion, the OP is looking for the average value in two decimal places. So, I would just cast that average field as decimal (5,2).  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8baed/13/0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
     , min.datetime min_time
     , max.datetime max_time
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DATE(datetime) date
            , MIN(value) min_value
            , MAX(value) max_value
            , AVG(value) 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY DATE(datetime)
     ) x
  JOIN my_table min
    ON DATE(min.datetime) = x.date
   AND min.value = x.min_value
  JOIN my_table max
    ON DATE(max.datetime) = x.date
   AND max.value = x.max_value;
```

Comment: This query does what I need it to do but still lists multiple minimums for 2015-05-01

Comment: It returns multiple columns for 2015-05-01 because you have two minimum values `12.3` for two different times.  `2015-05-01 06:00:00 | 12.3` and `2015-05-01 06:40:00 | 12.3`.

Comment: Correct. Min value occurred twice on 2015.03.01 but I would like the query to return just the first one.

Answer (score -1):

--

```
this will get you the mins.....
create table table1  
(_date datetime,
value float);

insert into table1 values (
'2015-05-01 06:00:00',  12.3)
,('2015-05-01 06:20:00',12.5)
<('2015-05-02 06:00:00', 19.2)
,('2015-05-02 06:20:00', 7.3)

select * from
 ( select min(value) as min1 ,cast(_date as date) as date1 from table1 group by cast(_date as date) )
 as i1
inner join
(select cast(_date as date) _date1,value, cast(_date as time) _time1 from table1)  as i2

on i1.min1= i2.value and
cast(i2._date1 as date)= i1.date1
```

Comment: I am impressed at how fast someone deducted a point without an explanation.

Comment: Clicking the button is a lot easier than typing, so don't be too surprised.